# TypeScript create array from Enum and then use it as parameter for a service call

Tags: angular, typescript, service, enums

I have an angular component with a simple service that extracts some data based on a parameter which happens to be an Enum.

```
export enum AgeEnum {
    UNDER_18 = 'UNDER_18',
    ABOVE_18 = 'ABOVE_18'
}
```

Then in my component I have the following:

```
private ageArray = Object.keys(AgeEnum);

private restrictionsWrapper: RestrictionsWrapper;

constructor(private restrictionsService: RestrictionsService) {
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRestrictionsForAge(this.ageArray);
}

private getRestrictionsForAge(ages: string[]) {
    for (const age of ages) {
        this.restrictionsService.getRestrictions(age as AgeEnum)
            .subscribe((options) => {
                    this.restrictionsWrapper.restrictions = options.restrictions;
                }, () => {
                    this.restrictionsWrapper.restrictions = null;
                }
            );
    }
}
```

My UI Service looks like this:

```
getRestrictions(age: AgeEnum): Observable<RestrictionsWrapper> {
    const params = new HttpParams().set('age', age);
    return this.http.get<RestrictionsWrapper>(BackendRoute.RESTRICTIONS, {params: params});
}
```

And this is my `RestrictionsWrapper` model:

```
export interface RestrictionsWrapper {
    restrictionDocuments: string[];
    blocked: boolean;
}
```

So basically, based on the age, i want to load a different set of 'restrictions'. 
But I don't want to have two separate methods where I pass two different ENUM values for each. I am getting an error:

```
Unhandled error occured. TypeError: Cannot set property 'restrictions' of undefined
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Is this actually correct (or good practice) `this.restrictionsService.getRestrictions(age as AgeEnum)` ?

Comment: Do you instantiate your `restrictionsWrapper` somewhere? Because it looks like you're not doing this and that would be the cause for your error message.

Comment: @Batajus, I added my model to the description too. My RestrictionsWrapper is actually an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your problem your `RestrictionsWrapper` is an interface. An interface only describes values and functions, which classes *need* to implement, but it's not an object.

Your error message `TypeError: Cannot set property 'restrictions' of undefined` tries to tell you that you are trying to do something like this: `undefined.restrictions = VALUE`.

To solve your problem you can choose between following two options:

**First:**

```
// Initialise your variable with an empty object
private restrictionsWrapper: RestrictionsWrapper = {};
```

**Second:**

In your component:

```
private restrictionsWrapper: RestrictionsWrapperClass;

constructor(private restrictionsService: RestrictionsService) {
    this.restrictionsWrapper = new RestrictionsWrapperClass();
}
```

In e.g. `restriction.api.ts`.

```
export class RestrictionsWrapperClass implements RestrictionsWrapper {

    restrictionDocuments: string[];
    blocked: boolean;

    constructor() {
        // Don't know, set some default values if you want
        this.restrictionDocuments = [];
        this.blocked = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

add

```
restrictionsWrapper = new RestrictionsWrapper();
```

inside the constructor or ngOnInit() of the controller or inside the getRestrictionsForAge() method.

The error occured because you are trying to initialize the properties of restrictionsWrapper before instantiating it

Comment: But my `RestrictionsWrapper` is an interface.

Comment: you can create a class that implements RestrictionsWrapper class which can be further instantiated @lapadets